# Angular 2 npm install error : (node:3240)

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

Hey I'm trying to make a MEAN 2.0 example work from [this](https://github.com/bradtraversy/mean_mytasklist) GitHub repo.

`Npm install` worked fine on the server folder but when I do `npm install` on client folder (Angular 2) I get this:

```
mytasklist@1.0.0 postinstall C:\wamp\Projects\mean_mytasklist\client
typings install

typings WARN deprecated 9/14/2016: "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759" is deprecated (upda                 ted, replaced or removed)
typings WARN deprecated 11/21/2016: "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046" is deprecated (update                 d, replaced or removed)
typings WARN deprecated 10/25/2016: "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255" is deprecated (upd                 ated, replaced or removed)
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Pops                 icleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyType                 d/c49913aa9ea419ea46c1c684e488cf2a10303b1a/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.10.34.36:443
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Pops                 icleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyType                 d/4008a51db44dabcdc368097a39a01ab7a5f9587f/node/node.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.10.34.36:443
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Pops                 icleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyType                 d/25e18b592470e3dddccc826fde2bb8e7610ef863/core-js/core-js.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.10.34.36:443
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): Pops                 icleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyType                 d/c49913aa9ea419ea46c1c684e488cf2a10303b1a/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.10.34.36:443
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 5): Pops                 icleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyType                 d/c49913aa9ea419ea46c1c684e488cf2a10303b1a/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.10.34.36:443
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): Pops                 icleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyType                 d/4008a51db44dabcdc368097a39a01ab7a5f9587f/node/node.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.10.34.36:443
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 7): Pops                 icleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyType                 d/25e18b592470e3dddccc826fde2bb8e7610ef863/core-js/core-js.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.10.34.36:443
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 8): Pops                 icleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyType                 d/c49913aa9ea419ea46c1c684e488cf2a10303b1a/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.10.34.36:443
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 9): Pops                 icleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyType                 d/4008a51db44dabcdc368097a39a01ab7a5f9587f/node/node.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.10.34.36:443
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 10): PopsicleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/25e18b592470e3dddccc826fde2bb8e7610ef863/core-js/core-js.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.10.34.36:443
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 11): PopsicleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/c49913aa9ea419ea46c1c684e488cf2a10303b1a/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.10.34.36:443
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 12): PopsicleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/25e18b592470e3dddccc826fde2bb8e7610ef863/core-js/core-js.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.10.34.36:443
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 13): PopsicleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/4008a51db44dabcdc368097a39a01ab7a5f9587f/node/node.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.10.34.36:443
(node:3240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 14): PopsicleError: Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/25e18b592470e3dddccc826fde2bb8e7610ef863/core-js/core-js.d.ts"
Caused by: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.10.34.36:443
typings ERR! message Unable to read typings for "jasmine". You should check the entry paths in "jasmine.d.ts" are up to date
typings ERR! caused by Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/c49913aa9ea419ea46c1c684e488cf2a10303b1a/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"
typings ERR! caused by connect ECONNREFUSED 10.10.34.36:443

typings ERR! cwd C:\wamp\Projects\mean_mytasklist\client
typings ERR! system Windows_NT 6.1.7601
typings ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\wamp\\Projects\\mean_mytasklist\\client\\node_modules\\typings\\dist\\bin.js" "install"
typings ERR! node -v v6.9.1
typings ERR! typings -v 1.4.0

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN mytasklist@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN mytasklist@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Mojtaba\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! mytasklist@1.0.0 postinstall: `typings install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mytasklist@1.0.0 postinstall script 'typings install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mytasklist package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs mytasklist
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mytasklist
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\wamp\Projects\mean_mytasklist\client\npm-debug.log
```

Tried `npm install` with and without proxy but that didn't work either. Looks like a problem with typings. What should I do?

> node v6.9.1
>   npm  v4.0.1

As mentioned above, if log file is needed I will upload that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `typings.json` from `client` folder and remove line `"postinstall": "typings install",` from your `client/package.json` file. Add below tree lines in your `client/package.json` :

```
"@types/node": "^6.0.46",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
"@types/selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.33"
```

Its giving you error because previously to install TypeScript declarations files, we had to install `DefinitelyTyped` packages using NuGet which we define in `typings.json` file but now we need to install `@types` based `npm` module to install TypeScript declarations. Check more details at  [Angular 2 with @types declaration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/notime/2016/09/23/angular-2-with-types-declaration-files/) files. You can find other `@types` modules list at npmjs on [Packages by types](https://www.npmjs.com/~types)

Comment: i did and get this 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN mytasklist@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN mytasklist@1.0.0 No repository field.

Comment: That's different issue and its still open as https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11069. But you can now start your application.